# scrollIntoView possible with form submit -> page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css, js-scrollintoview

Edit: I got what I want with adding #divname to the form action. Pretty dumb that I didn't try this earlier

So I want to scroll back down my page when I press the submit button and the page refreshes using JS. (or HTML CSS methods if there are)

There were a few answers with window.onload but that doesn't work for me. (it works when I click the button and then refresh again, then it goes down my page)

this is my JS now:

```
const scrollTo = () => {

  window.onload = function() {
    const $results = document.querySelector(`results`);
    $results.scrollIntoView(true);
  };
};

export default () => {
  const $filterbutton = document.querySelector(`.filter_button`);

  $filterbutton.addEventListener(`click`, scrollTo);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the

```
Element.scrollIntoView()
```

to make an element visible. Also as you are refresing the page, you can add an anchor tag in your html, and use it in the url:

```
myserver.com/my_page.htm#my_position_in_page
```

Comment: Element.scrollIntoView() is what I'm using right now isn't it? and can I add an anchor to my page link with a submit button?

Comment: Seeing your code...when you click on the button you execute the scrollFunction, but the window.load does not get executed at all.  The event OnLoad only fires after the page has loaded.

Comment: So... what should I do? Taking away the window.onload doesn't work either since the page does reload after clicking the submit button

Comment: When the page reloads, all elements are "recreated" this means that the element variable does not survive a page reload. Move the onload out of the scroll function, so that it gets executed. In the onload method you need to differentiate if this is the first or the second load, if this is the second then look for the element and execute scrollIntoView